# Issues changing directories to folder inside nested folders with my bash script

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I am mainly curious as to why this script is not working properly...

Here is my shell script file:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                      
#move to a specific folder                                                                       

echo "moving to templates folder"                                                                
cd /home/mussta/general/retentionApp/retentionApp/templates
exec bash
```

The issue is that when I run command, it takes me to:

/home/mussta/general/retentionApp/retentionApp/

But nothing I do will take me inside the templates folder...

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: after the `cd` run `pwd` e.g. `cd ..... && pwd`, does that say your inside the directory you want to go into? Also do you know what the `exec` is doing?

Comment: When I do 'pwd' it does show that I am in templates!? But when I type 'ls' it shows me the contents of the retentionApp folder rather than the templates folder. Why is this?

Comment: A child process can never affect any part of the parent's environment, which includes its variables, its current working directory, its open files, its resource limits, etc

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand what that means in relation to my question.

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/060

Comment: Okay, so I need to remove 'exec bash' and then run the command with a full stop in front (or source). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to Jetchisel's comments, the answer was (or my understanding of it at least), is that the script is running in a new shell and so you end up back where you started after the new shell closes...

Anyway, the way that I fixed it was by removing `exec bash` and by running the file with `. commandname`